# Use sonar to prevent a commit if code coverage QG is not met

Tags: git, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have recently added the sonarqube plugin to my Maven project in conjunction with jacoco for unit and integration test coverage.

Things are working well and I can see on my Sonar dashboard my current rate of code coverage and if I miss my quality gate for code coverage on new builds.

What I would like to do however is prevent git commits based on the QG result. Example workflow:

1. Make some changes
2. git commit
3. Pre-commit git hook fires that causes a build and sonar check
4. Code coverage is not > 80% for the new code so fail and prevent the commit

Is this possible or do I have to commit the code and wait until I can see the detail in the dashboard?

Comment: well, usually you can always make an amend later. So the general workflow looks like this: you make a commit and then a check system is fired either automatically or manually, and you continue your usual work. Then when CC results arrive, and you have time to study it, probably for several commits at once, you can switch to result processing and make necessary ammends to those commits

Comment: This makes sense for any bugs found in the code but when it just comes down to ensuring the dev has written their unit tests, I think it is fair to prevent them making the commit in the first place until it's done.

Comment: well, you certainly could put anything into the pre-commit hook, and it will be executed, but and the control will be returned back to git only when that verifying code completed, and so on. But heck, usually CC tests aren't that fast for any project beyond helloworld. So your developers will be waiting for CC completion longer and longer, as the codebase grows. Do they have per-hour or per-codeline rate? :)

Comment: Usually a proper code-review system with a CI system attached to _code-review_ not to code creation works much smoother. A developer creates one or several commits, small enough and logically structured so that they can be easily reviewed by human beings and pushes the whole work to a review server. Then and there automatic verification procedures are fired (not necessarily CC, others like codestyle checks etc fit this point well). Then the developer collects responses both from robots and human  colleagues and makes fixes for the entire commit chain, one commit by one.

Comment: I am willing to let the dev commit if it has to be done and @G. Ann mentioned below that there are plugins available that will automatically add comments to PRs but she notes that this doesn't include CC.

Therefore, the dev has to visit another system (Sonar dashboard) just to check CC is met. It all seems very hard. I just want to get the CC % of the delta and say "No! Go write some more tests" without human involvement.

Comment: well, human interaction isn't necessary. As @G.Ann mentioned below, robots are fired automatically on certain stages of the process. And without [prior] approve from robots humans even won't pay attention. Regarding CC: in real life CC takes considerable time (up to a few hours), so it's simply unwise to fire it on each commit  - you'd put the CI system down to its knees or stop developers' work completely.

Comment: You can configure the Jacoco to check the coverage and break the build. Seems a better option to me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the end result you seek is possible with a different workflow. Take a look at the [GitHub Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin). It comments on *pull requests*. So if instead of committing to master you commit to a branch and create a pull request, this plugin will scan for and comment on the code with new issues*. A human reviewer can then decide whether or not to merge.

*Not all rules are run in this scan. E.G. rules about duplications and coverage are not included

Comment: I've looked at the similar plugin available for Bitbucket as that's what we use.  Unfortunately, as you point out, CC is not commented on so doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding question here about whether you want the coverage

(a) on the project overall; or

(b) on the lines changed in your commit (this is what sonar does well *after* your commit

Before we talk about automated solutions - for manual solutions - you can run:

(a) for the project overall - you can get a manual result with jacoco

(b) for the coverage on the lines changed in your commit - you can look at: https://github.com/juliangamble/commit-level-coverage-report